# Engajamento usuários do sistema

Tags: php

Temos um sistema de helpdesk, e estamos desenvolvendo um FAQ, minha pergunta é como faço para conseguir um maior engajamento por parte dos usuários. Ex: Aqui no stackoverflow se usa as conquistas, pontuação gostaria de algo semelhante.

O sistema gerencia chamados, tickets e atendimentos é entre a empresa desenvolvedora do sistemas e seus representante.

Comment: Muito legal a sua pergunta, vou marcar como favorito pra ver as respostas.

Comment: Se é um sistema de suporte, basta a empresa contratar alguém para que controle a aplicação. É um ambiente completamente diferente do que é o [pt.so]. No seu sistema haverão apenas dois utilizadores: o cliente, que utilizará por necessidade, e o responsável técnico, que é pago para isso. Quem mais você iria engajar para utilizar o sistema?

Comment: Você está querendo gamificar o seu suporte? Se os chamados forem abertos, pode até ser que funcione, que haja colaboração da sociedade além do suporte. Caso contrário, não acredito que pontos e medalhas farão alguma diferença natural no uso do sistema. Talvez isso cause inclusive chamados desnecessários e, de certo modo, puxão de orelha nos desenvolvedores por existir chamados demais (pois dependendo da métrica da empresa significa que o desenvolvimento seja taxado como "incompetente")

Comment: Essa pergunta tratando cerne da sua preocupação: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243567/64969

Comment: É um sistema que possui 3 lados (Cliente, Representante e Software house) a ideia é encorajar os usuários (Clientes e representantes) a fazer perguntas para ser colocado no FAQ, temos um WIKI também que não tem uma engajamento esperado.