# O que é gamificação no contexto de software?

Tags: terminologia, gamificação

Recentemente vi alguns comentários sobre `gamificação` e gostaria de entender o que é e como funciona no contexto de software.

Como isso se relaciona com programação propriamente dita?

Comment: Dica, você está a usá-la neste exato site e momento.

Comment: A resposta curta é que gamificação é um conjunto de interações com o usuário para que ele se engaje no uso de uma ferramenta. E que o engajamento venha de fatores internos do próprio usuário. Vou fazer uma resposta mais detalhada depois

Comment: Gamificacao é uma ideia boba, uma vez que ela desmotiva, diminuí o esforco e pode resultar em efeitos indesejados. [Fonte](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0360131514002000). Pelo menos no contexto da educacao.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Uma vez que o artigo não é de livre acesso (é preciso comprá-lo), fica difícil argumentar sobre seus resultados. Pelo *abstract* eles afirmam que usaram *badges* e *leaderboards* e que os alunos demonstraram menor motivação, satisfação e empoderamento em comparação a uma turma sem esses elementos. Uma questão que eu julgo relevante é se esses resultados não foram decorrentes da insatisfação com as expectativas criadas justamente com uma gamificação mal feita. Até aí, dizer que é "ideia boba" é complicado porque o conceito funciona em muitos contextos, inclusive educacionais. :)

Comment: Mas, eu acho que esta pergunta é complicada. A resposta existente explica brevemente o que é gamificação, mas falha em fazer a relação que o AP quer (e que tornaria ela válida neste site): a relação com software. Além do mais, "contexto de software" ainda é amplo. Estamos falando do desenvolvimento profissional de software? Do seu uso comercial? Do aprendizado (sobre como desenvolver, ou sobre como usar certo software)? P.S.: Não fui eu quem negativou.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243812/64969

Answer (score 8):

[Eu já dei a minha visão sobre o que é Gamificação em outra pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/244462/73). Então, queria focar aqui na segunda parte da sua pergunta: **qual é a relação com software**.

Como uma ferramenta para auxiliar na motivação intrínseca das pessoas, a gamificação pode ser utilizada no contexto do desenvolvimento de software assim como em qualquer outro contexto. Porém é primeiramente necessário entender qual é o objetivo de design (observe que é diferente do objetivo do participante) intencionado. Em outras palavras, qual é o comportamento que se deseja atribuir aos participantes? Você quer que eles utilizem o software de forma mais correta, que eles programem o software de forma mais robusta, ou que eles se interessem por aprender a fazer software? Cada uma dessas perguntas é um produto/processo diferente, em que certos métodos/técnicas/ferramentas podem ser mais ou menos úteis.

Por exemplo, oferecer medalhas (*badges*) a usuários de um website como o Stackoverflow pode fazer com que eles se interessem pelo conteúdo muito específico ou por uma tarefa naturalmente pouco gratificante (como fazer análises de perguntas de outras pessoas) justamente pela busca por tais medalhas, mas em outros contextos em que o usuário já está motivado de forma extrínseca (porque é seu emprego e ele deve usar o sistema, por exemplo), as medalhas podem ser enxergadas meramente como um estorvo.

[O colega Bruno comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243567/o-que-%c3%a9-gamifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-contexto-de-software#comment499105_243567) que a gamificação pode não funcionar no contexto de educação, e isso é realmente uma grande possibilidade. No exemplo citado (que não é de livre acesso, então não dá pra ter mais detalhes), uma possibilidade que eu já vi acontecer tem relação com a criação de expectativas. Ao se mencionar a alunos que a aula será "gamificada" (terá elementos de jogos), a expectativa criada é bastante grande principalmente quando a aula tradicional já é enxergada como algo chato e entediante. Se a gamificação for realizada de forma superficial (por exemplo, em que medalhas sem qualquer ligação a uma fantasia consistente e de interesse dos "jogadores" são dadas por tarefas realizadas), ela pode falhar completamente e, de fato, conduzir a experiência para o sentido oposto do intencionado (o aluno achar que a medalha é a nota da prova travestida de medalha, e assim ficar ainda mais chateado por causa da falha em cumprir uma grande expectativa criada).

Mas isso não quer dizer que tentativas assim não tenham alcançado sucesso na educação. Em São Paulo há um grupo chamado ["Interpretar e Aprender"](https://www.facebook.com/InterpretarEAprender/) que utiliza jogos de RPG para auxiliar no ensino de História, e que tem motivado muitos alunos a se interessar pelo assunto.

> Aqui há um ponto importante de discussão, a respeito de isso se tratar
>   de um "jogo sério" ou de uma gamificação - vide o gráfico de Deterding
>   et al. que eu cito na minha outra resposta já referenciada. O fato é
>   que elementos da História são conduzidos em meio a muitas sessões de
>   jogo, com diferentes pessoas e recriando contextos sociais as vezes
>   bastante difíceis de reconhecer fora do círculo do jogo, de forma que
>   isso pra mim está muito mais para um processo do que para um produto.

No ensino de computação há inúmeros exemplos, mas eu gosto de citar o jogo online chamado [CodeCombat](https://codecombat.com/) (este sim, muito mais próximo de um jogo sério do que de um processo gamificado). Mesmo sendo um jogo, ele tem motivado muitas pessoas a se interessarem mais por programação e a fazerem exercícios de forma lúdica. Utilizado num contexto acadêmico, o jogo é uma ferramenta em um processo maior, e nesse caso eu diria que se trata de uma gamificação envolvendo o aprendizado de software.

Em resumo, a relação da gamificação com o software é tangencial, assim como é a relação do desenvolvimento de jogos (sérios ou não) com sofware. Jogos digitais requerem programação envolvendo um sistema de computador, mas jogos analógicos (de tabuleiro, cartas, dados, etc) [já existem há mais de 3 mil anos](https://thinking-stoneman.blogspot.com.br/2013/01/the-oldest-game-in-world.html). O jogo desse link em particular ([da família Mancala](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mancala)) envolve uma mecânica que simula a semeadura de sementes na terra e, principalmente, a percepção de que você não pode vencer se o seu adversário morrer de fome. Assim como o Xadrez e o [Senet](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senet), esses primeiros jogos tinham uma forte relação com questões fundamentais para as civilizações humanas: respectivamente a agricultura, a guerra e a religião. O uso desses jogos, enxergado nesse contexto mais amplo, não deixa de fazer deles ferramentas em um processo gamificado, com a intenção de motivar algum comportamento ou gerar conscientização.

Em conclusão: a gamificação precede o software; mas pode se valer dele como ferramenta, ou pode ser utilizada para motivar algum comportamento relacionado ao seu uso, desenvolvimento ou aprendizado.

Answer (score 7):

"Gamificação" é um termo usado quando um sistema ou campanha quer fazer com que o usuário se sinta engajado para conquistar alguma coisa, seja status, pontuação ou prêmios, como num jogo, como uma forma mais [lúdica](https://www.significados.com.br/ludico/) de "prender" o usuário (*o StackOverflow pode ser citado como um exemplo típico disso*).

O termo deriva de "game" (jogo), quando em todo jogo, o *jogador* busca pontuar o mais alto possível com seu esforço e assiduidade, fazendo com que ele se sinta instigado a continuar no jogo afim de buscar mais pontos, criando uma fidelização do usuário.

*Gamificação* não está ligada diretamente com programação, pois isso pode ser feito de diversas formas, sem envolver programação. No caso de programação, apenas envolve como será feito o código (software) onde o programador escreve o programa que irá controlar a forma do "jogo" funcionar (*back-end*).

Answer (score 6):

Gamificação, do inglês *gamification* (de *game)*, é a promoção do engajamento do público em certo produto ou serviço por meio de maneiras alternativas.

As comunidades do StackExchange, o StackOverflow em Português é uma delas, [promovem a gamificação](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-gamification/). Os pontos, medalhas, privilégios e a interação social cativam o usuário a perguntar e responder mais.

Um aplicativo conhecido para aprendizado de idiomas, Duolingo, também [promove a ludificação através do sistema competitivo](http://www.gamification.co/2015/08/12/gamified-design-review-a-in-depth-analysis-of-duolingo/).

Esse conceito todo não se prende ao mundo virtual. [Empresas estão gamificando processos para engajar seus funcionários](https://www.clicksoftware.com/blog/top-25-best-examples-of-gamification-in-business/) a buscarem mais produtividade, conhecimento e etc.

A [primeira referência](http://www.nanodome.com/conundra.co.uk/) de "gamification" foi em 2002-2003 por Nick Pelling, embora tenha sido popularizado a partir de 2010, como mostra este gráfico com a frequência de buscas:

[image]
 <sub>Fonte: [Google Trends (gamification)](https://trends.google.com.br/trends/explore?date=all&q=gamification)</sub>

As citações dos *cases* anteriores são relacionados à software. De forma simples é procurar os métodos de gamificação aplicáveis à sua solução e começar a implementação, seja o sistema de pontuação, o *ranking*, ou outro. O ideal é analisar resultados para ver se os mesmos surtem, aumentando o engajamento ou outro objetivo maior.

O mais legal desse campo de estudo é que não envolve somente software. Como toda área relacionada a [ux](/questions/tagged/ux), é comum ver psicologia (principalmente comportamental).

No mais, vamos ver quem ganha o “resposta aceita” nessa pergunta

<sub>Essa pergunta gerou [essa](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4832/qual-a-origem-e-significado-da-palavra-gamifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o/4836), no Portuguese Language!</sub>

Comment: Isso aí! Parabens! +1

Answer (score 3):

Gameficação (ou gamefication) é a incorporação de elementos típicos de jogos em aplicações não relacionadas com este contexto, com objetivo de aumentar a empatia com o público-alvo.

Um exemplo prático é a gameficação aplicada ao ensino no qual o aluno é instigado a cumprir, progressivamente, atividades através de um sistema de pontos e recompensas de forma a tornar o processo inteiro lúdico, as atividades tornam-se mais desafiadoras na medida em que o aluno avança, replicando assim o sistema de fases de um jogo.

O uso de gráficos e desenho divertidos, a competitividade, o trabalho em equipe e a socialização com outros "jogadores" são estratégia que podem cumprir um importante papel na gameficação de uma aplicação.

No tocante ao e-learning pesquisei algumas práticas que podem ser aplicadas em fiz o seguinte resumo:

O artigo abaixo trás algumas considerações complementares muito interessantes que ampliarão seu entendimento sobre isso. Vale a pena conferir.

https://elearningindustry.com/6-killer-examples-gamification-in-elearning

Comment: Engraçado que você citar o exemplo do aprendizado como um dos possíveis usos da gamificação entra em conflito com o artigo linkado no [comentário do Bruno Costa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243567/o-que-%c3%a9-gamifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-contexto-de-software#comment499105_243567)

Comment: Procurei a referência que você passou aqui, mas encontrei o seguinte trecho no comentário do Bruno Costa: "(...) o conceito funciona em muitos contextos, inclusive educacionais.". Não entendi em que sentido afirma haver contraditoriedade. Você pode elaborar um pouco mais seu ponto de vista?

Comment: eu só li o resumo, tem isso em um dos pontos da conclusão que ele põe no resumo

Comment: Esse trecho: "Over time, gamified students were less motivated, empowered, and satisfied."

Comment: @CaiubyFreitas Esse comentário que você citou é do Luiz Vieira.

Comment: O conteúdo do referido artigo não é aberto ao público, daí o motivo da citação. Talvez seja interessante ler o artigo completo. Em todo caso, é preciso que entenda que a explicação que forneci não é resultado de uma tese, nem pretende contra-argumentar o trabalho do referido Bruno Costa. Trata-se tão-somente da explicação de um termo de uso comum e, independemente do ratio que se faça sobre sentido, relevância e resultados da gameficação, tem tão-somente o objetivo de prestar esclarecimento. Talvez aqui não seja o lugar para debates acadêmicos aprofundados.

Comment: Oi obrigado pela atenção. Você diz que fez um resumo, seria o que vem antes da afirmação ou ainda irá acrescentar, veja não é um acrítica a sua resposta, mas a afirmação deixa um gostinho de "quero mais"...;)

Comment: _"Como isso se relaciona com programação propriamente dita?"_

Comment: Qual é a ortografia correta: "gameficação" ou "gamificação"? Ou é a mesma coisa?

Comment: "Gamificação" é o correto segundo o Priberam. @Dvdsamm